# Get at a categories image in PHP | Magento2

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get at a categories image from within PHP / a .phtml file.

Here is my code:

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_children  = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
foreach( $_children as $child ){
    if( $child->getIsActive() ){
        echo "<p>" . $child->getImageUrl() . "</p>";
```

This last line results in an empty string. When I `var_dump` it, I get the following:

```
bool(false)
```

Upon further investigation, this `getImageUrl` function is defined in `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php` on line 656, like so:

```
public function getImageUrl(){
    $url = false;
    $image = $this->getImage();
    if ($image) {
```

The problem here is that `$this->getImage()` returns `NULL`. Nowhere in `Category.php` can I find the function `getImage`, and all of this makes me think that there is no `getImage` function in the Category class.

Is this correct? Do we need to add a `getImage` method to the class to make `getImageUrl` work?

Or is `getImage` inherited from elsewhere? And in this case, why is it returning `NULL`?

---

Disclaimers:

This is Magento 2.0.2.

I am not about to alter core code, I already have a theme of my own, and if I was to add a new function to the Category class I would extend the core code in my theme.

I have re-indexed, I have cleared caches, I have re-deployed.